# NULL скрипты

Tags: php, html, javascript, mysql

Есть ли разница между NULL скриптом и лицензией. И какие могут быть последствие с NULL скриптом. Например: какой нибудь бан или еще что нибудь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null могут быть корявыми. Так же в них могут вшить код, как вредный, так и безвредный (ссылки будут генерироваться на сторонние сайты и т.д.). Можно боятся того, что разработчики найдут ваш сайт и постараются его "уничтожить" написав хостеру. В данном случае вам просто придется поискать другой хостинг.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Жаль что все так может быть печально :(